# Why am I getting a ForeignKeyConstraint when filling a datatable and the dataset.EnforceConstraints is set to false?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to load a dataset from a database using `dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)` and I've turned off the contraints in the DataSet, but I'm still getting an exception thrown. 
[image]

Comment: Does the underlying table have the a foreign key relationship?if it does it is sql throwing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha.
It was the data adapter enabling the constraints after loading the data.

I must say this is a pain because I turned off the constraints so I wouldn't have to load each table in order.  Do I resort to using a DataReader instead to avoid constraint enabling after each table fill?

Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.    **at System.Data.DataSet.EnableConstraints()
   at System.Data.DataSet.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
   at System.Data.DataTable.EndLoadData()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)**
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)